# Selenium: Checking if several elements are not visible takes too much time

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In one of my testcases, im checking if some elements are NOT visible.

Its very simple:

1. Login
2. Check if 5 buttons inside the left menu bar are **not** visible (As the user has no rights)
3. End test

This shouldnt take more than 10 seconds to test.

But as im using implicit wait, it does always wait 5 seconds for each button, which causes the test to take way too much time to finish. Currently it takes more than 30 seconds just to test if 5 buttons are not visible.

Im using this method:

```
var elements = _webDriver.FindElements(By.XPath(selector));
if (elements.Count > 0)
{
   throw new Exception(selector + " still displayed");
}
```

Are there any other ways how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Use a explicit wait to check for the first element and then just check the other elements directly (with implicitly_wait = 0).

something like:

```
try:
   element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
      EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, selector))
   )
except TimeoutException:
   # no element found
if element:
   # check the presence of the other elements with find_element
```

documentation:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html